# AngularJS ng-repeat checkbox update ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-templates

I have a problem (possibly a simple one) ..

I have an array with "product" `objects`, `$scope.products` .. these products are listed as `checkboxes`.

Now I have a new array with the "product" objects which are selected "chosen ones", the array is loaded with a `async promise` ..

Now I need a way to check only the `checkboxes` with the chosen products..

How to do that .. ;)

```
$scope.products // array with product objects
$scope.chosenproducts // array with chosen product objects - async

// template
<label ng-repeat="product in products">
       <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="chosenproducts"  ng-true-value="{{product}}" 
              ng-false-value="{}" 
              ng-disabled="case.shared"> 
        {{product.name}}
</label>
```

this is  my badly try .. won't work ..

Comment: are `$scope.products` and `$scope.chosenproducts` the same model? if yes you can just  put `$scope.products = $scope.chosenproducts` after you promise had been returned

Comment: no .. i need to show all the products, and then only check the products from the chosenproducts array, which are loaded from the server afterwards..

Comment: Can you show us a sample of how your `products` and `chosenproducts` arrays look like? You could probaly merge the `chosenproducts` with `products` when it is received.

Comment: Yes, this is very much possible, however it is very hard to  show you how to do it without seeing the structure of the data you are bringing in. Can you please show what the structure of the data in `$scope.products` and `$scope.chosenproducts` looks like? You don't need to show the entire payload, just what the general structure looks like for each. Otherwise trying to tailor an answer for you is really shooting in the dark...